# which is having first priority Cross Product or Vector addition?

Tags: vector-spaces, cross-product

If $$\vec{r}=\vec{a}\times \vec{b}+\vec{c}$$

Does it mean $$\vec{r}=\left(\vec{a}\times \vec{b}\right)+\vec{c}$$

Or

$$\vec{r}=\vec{a}\times\left( \vec{b}+\vec{c}\right)$$

Comment: I think the first like always.

Comment: I think the first given that products have a higher precedence as a rule. If this is from a physics/vector calculus text, then context will more or less inevitably tell you which is intended. Only in an isolated context (as an exercise in vector manipulations) could there be much doubt.